# Is SHAKE hash function seekable when using it as a stream cipher?

Tags: hash, stream-cipher, sha-3

I searched a lot for this information in search engines as well as taking a look in the [SHAKE reference implementation](https://github.com/KeccakTeam/KeccakCodePackage).

If I decide to use SHAKE as a stream cipher, can I access a specific part of the keystream without having to generate previous data from the beginning?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's not seekable. However, the [Keccak team](https://keccak.team) define [other](https://keccak.team/files/CSF-0.1.pdf#page=21) modes of operation for the permutation that may fit your needs.

Comment: That seekable stream cipher described in that page is very interesting, I bookmarked because I'm going to try to implement in the future.